# Parsley Upgrade throwing PubSub deprecation error

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, parsley.js

I upgraded from Parsley 2.0.6 to 2.2.0 and now I get this warning in the console:

> Parsley's pubsub module is deprecated; use the 'on' and 'off' methods on parsley instances or window.Parsley

Everything still works, including the functions triggered by the parsley event listeners, in which (I believe) this error finds its root. But I get the warning. Whenever I do stuff to remove the warning, then the function doesn't run.

I've changed the `$.listen('parsley:field:validated')` to every combination of jQuery `.on()`. I've also updated the parsley event to `field:validated'. No matter what I do, my function fails to run. Here's a chunk of the original relevant code. This is the code that works, but shows the warning in the console:

```
// check forms for data-parsley-validate attribute. If exists, then extend the config
// with the trigger:'change' option.
$('form, .form').each(function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    if($form.is('[data-parsley-validate]')) {
        ParsleyConfig = $.extend(ParsleyConfig || {}, {
            trigger: 'change'
        });
    }
    $form.parsley();
});


$(function () {
    // Validation listener for adjusting height of certain other components/widgets
    $.listen('parsley:form:validated', $('[data-modal]'), function () {
        if (typeof modalHeightSetter == 'function') { modalHeightSetter(); }
    });

    // Validation listener for add/removal of .error class from .field-icon's
    $.listen('parsley:field:validated', $('[data-field-icon]'), function() {
        var $fieldIcons = $(this);
        $fieldIcons.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.is('.error')) {
                $this.prev('.field-icon').addClass('error');
            } else if(! $this.is('.error')) {
                $this.prev('.field-icon').removeClass('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I rewrote the js in question per what I think @Mark-Andre was saying, but got the same result of the deprecation warning going away, but the functions not running.

```
// check forms for data-parsley-validate attribute. If exests, then extend the config
// with the trigger:'change' option.
$('form, .form').each(function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    if($form.is('[data-parsley-validate]')) {
        ParsleyConfig = $.extend(ParsleyConfig || {}, {
            trigger: 'change'
        });
    }
    $form.parsley();
    // Validation listener for ajdusting height of certain other components/widgets
    $form.parsley().on('form:validated', $('[data-modal]'), function () {
        if (typeof modalHeightSetter == 'function') { modalHeightSetter(); }
    });

    // Validation listener for add/removal of .error class from .field-icon's
    $form.parsley().on('field:validated', $('[data-field-icon]'), function() {
        var $fieldIcons = $(this);
        $fieldIcons.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.is('.error')) {
                $this.prev('.field-icon').addClass('error');
            } else if(! $this.is('.error')) {
                $this.prev('.field-icon').removeClass('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [the doc](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#events)... The `on` and `off` methods are not jQuery's but Parsley's...

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean now.  Testing it out

Comment: The `this` is the parsley instance, not the DOM element